# Supremum of derivatives of absolutely continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ be a compact set of absolutely continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with the norm $\|f\| = |f(0)| + \int_0^1|\dot{f}(t)|dt$. Can we always find a Lebesgue integrable function $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $g(t) \ge |\dot{f}(t)|$ for all $f \in A$ and $t \in [0,1]$? Is the set of essential supremums of $|\dot{f}(t)|$ bounded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usual trick: Let 
$$p_n(x) = \begin{cases} n+1 &\text{when }x\in \left( \frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}\right), \\ 0 &\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

and

$$f_n(x) = \int_0^x p_n(s) ds.$$

Then $\|f_n\| = \frac{1}{n}$ and thus $\{f_n\}$ converges in $\| \cdot\|$ to the zero function. In particular,

$$A = \{ f_n\} \cup \{0\}$$

is a compact set. But $x\mapsto \sup_n |\dot {f_n}(x)|$ is not an integrable function.